# Consuming XML REST

Tags: c#, xml, rest, serialization

I want to consuming XML REST [image]

I have searched on Google and I created this code:

```
public partial class XtraForm_Main : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
    public XtraForm_Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void simpleButton_Import_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.10.141:4004/Code/WcfService_REST_SuiviColis/WcfService_REST_SuiviColis/Service1.svc/ListOrdre");
        WebResponse ws = request.GetResponse();

        //Stream oStream = ws.GetResponseStream();
        //StreamReader oReader = new StreamReader(oStream);
        //string res = oReader.ReadToEnd();

        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Pers_Ordre_Local));
        Pers_Ordre_Local photos = (Pers_Ordre_Local)s.Deserialize(ws.GetResponseStream());
    }
}

[XmlRoot("ArrayOfPers_Ordre")]
public class Pers_Ordre_Local
{
        [XmlElement("CodeClient")]
        string _CodeClient;
        public string CodeClient
        {
            get { return _CodeClient; }
            set { _CodeClient = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement("CodeDest")]
        string _CodeDest;
        public string CodeDest
        {
            get { return _CodeDest; }
            set { _CodeDest = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement("NoOrdre")]
        string _NoOrdre;
        public string NoOrdre
        {
            get { return _NoOrdre; }
            set { _NoOrdre = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement("LeDate")]
        string _LeDate;
        public string LeDate
        {
            get { return _LeDate; }
            set { _LeDate = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement("LeGPS")]
        string _LeGPS;
        public string LeGPS
        {
            get { return _LeGPS; }
            set { _LeGPS = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement("LeStatut")]
        string _LeStatut;
        public string LeStatut
        {
            get { return _LeStatut; }
            set { _LeStatut = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement("LeCamion")]
        string _LeCamion;
        public string LeCamion
        {
            get { return _LeCamion; }
            set { _LeCamion = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement("LeOrdrePos")]
        string _LeOrdrePos;
        public string LeOrdrePos
        {
            get { return _LeOrdrePos; }
            set { _LeOrdrePos = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement("LeOrdreTot")]
        string _LeOrdreTot;
        public string LeOrdreTot
        {
            get { return _LeOrdreTot; }
            set { _LeOrdreTot = value; }
        }
}
```

I get an error :

> There is an error of the XML Document (1,2)

and when I debug it, I found the error because of this:

```
<ArrayOfPers_Ordre xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService_REST_SuiviColis" 
                   xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

but I don't know how to solve it. How can I parse this xml document?

i have change my class into this, but stil got the same error.

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("ArrayOfPers_Ordre"), XmlType("ArrayOfPers_Ordre")]
    public class ListOfOrdes
    {
        public ListOfOrdes()
        {
            oOrdre = new List<Pers_Ordre_Local>();
        }

        [XmlElement("Pers_Ordre")]
        public List<Pers_Ordre_Local> oOrdre { get; set; }
    }


    [XmlType("Pers_Ordre")]
    public class Pers_Ordre_Local
    {
        [XmlElement("CodeClient")]
        string _CodeClient;
        public string CodeClient
        {
            get { return _CodeClient; }
            set { _CodeClient = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement("CodeDest")]
        string _CodeDest;
        public string CodeDest
        {
            get { return _CodeDest; }
            set { _CodeDest = value; }
        }

       [XmlElement("NoOrdre")]
        string _NoOrdre;
        public string NoOrdre
        {
            get { return _NoOrdre; }
            set { _NoOrdre = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement("LeDate")]
        string _LeDate;
        public string LeDate
        {
            get { return _LeDate; }
            set { _LeDate = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement("LeGPS")]
        string _LeGPS;
        public string LeGPS
        {
            get { return _LeGPS; }
            set { _LeGPS = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement("LeStatut")]
        string _LeStatut;
        public string LeStatut
        {
            get { return _LeStatut; }
            set { _LeStatut = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement("LeCamion")]
        string _LeCamion;
        public string LeCamion
        {
            get { return _LeCamion; }
            set { _LeCamion = value; }
        }

       [XmlElement("LeOrdrePos")]
        string _LeOrdrePos;
        public string LeOrdrePos
        {
            get { return _LeOrdrePos; }
            set { _LeOrdrePos = value; }
        }

       [XmlElement("LeOrdreTot")]
        string _LeOrdreTot;
        public string LeOrdreTot
        {
            get { return _LeOrdreTot; }
            set { _LeOrdreTot = value; }
        }
```

Comment: The simplest way to make sure your class is setup right to deserialize into is to copy the xml into the clipboard.  In visual studio use the edit--> paste special --> paste xml as class into a new code file.

Comment: thanks for your response, <ArrayOfPers_Ordre xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService_REST_SuiviColis" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Pers_Ordre><CodeClient>850973</CodeClient><CodeDest>1430136</CodeDest><LeCamion i:nil="true"/><LeDate>17/12/2015 00:00:00</LeDate><LeGPS i:nil="true"/><LeOrdrePos i:nil="true"/><LeOrdreTot i:nil="true"/><LeStatut i:nil="true"/><NoOrdre>2308959</NoOrdre></Pers_Ordre>......</Pers_Ordre</ArrayOfPers_Ordre>